# "Command" behavior in Crystal Reports slowing down edits

Tags: sql, sql-server, command-line, crystal-reports

Google failed me :( I guess this isn't something very many people need. Here's the situation -

I like to test my SQL queries in SMSS before I import them into the Command module in Crystal Reports, but I've noticed that if I make *any* changes after the first import Crystal hangs for a while. My guess is that Crystal is testing the query on the server before it will let me go back to the report designer.

I want to know if it is possible to disable it checking the query before going back to the designer view. Sometimes I might make a very simple/minor alteration, like editing an alias, but it still rechecks the entire query. If it's a query takes a few minutes to pull results from the server this really slows down the implementation of these minor edits.

Because I have always test the SQL in SMSS first, I don't really need Crystal to check it as well, I already know it will return results without error. So, is there a way to bypass this step in Crystal?

Thanks for your insight :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean minor changes to the SQL query, or minor changes in the report?

If it's the former, CR will always re-process the query when a change was made to it, even if all you did was open the Command table and change 'as field1' to 'as field_1'. No getting around that.

If you mean a minor change in CR designing the report, then there are a few things to note:

- CR seems to only cache data for fields that are within the report itself, so if you've only placed 2 fields out of 20 from your result set into the report, CR has to refresh the query to get the data when you drag in or reference a 3rd field. I'm not aware of a setting that changes this.

This leaves two options, at least that I use, to work around it:

1. Work only or mostly in design mode, without preview. Therein, you can write as many formulas against different fields, add/remove items, etc., and CR won't retrieve additional items until you preview.
2. If you want to easily preview your changes "live" as you make them, (my usual course of action) then create a hidden section and drag all of your fields into it. This will force CR to retrieve everything at once, and so it will not need to hit the data source/server again & again every time you make a change. It will simply go through "recalculating formulas" which can still take some time depending on the report, but it's still a great reduction in time spent waiting waiting.

If you take option #2, I would advise that you then remove/delete the hidden section after design completion. This will reduce overhead for any computing resources involved, and avoid a potential security risk of including data that isn't used but might be sensitive.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed update. Unfortunately it is the first scenario you describe that I was hoping to find a solution for. Oh well, I guess I just have to get better at making my SQL perfect the first time around.

I like your suggestion for "live" updates in the CR preview panel though, will definitely be using that in the future. :)

Comment: Well, there's no way around CR re-validating, but you may be able to get around it a little bit by creating indexed views of your most frequent queries. As these will be presented to CR as a table, there will be no need for CR to re-validate, and so you will offload a little bit of that processing back to the server. If the server takes just as long, then this won't help, but in my experience ODBC connections made through CR as usually a bit more sluggish than I can achieve with SSMS or a 3rd party tool like SQL Maestro.

Comment: Actually, if the server is taking a long time to process the query as well, an indexed view would improve performance all around.